# I am a Jamaican citizen granted asylum in the United States. May I use my refugee travel documents to visit the Bahamas?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, refugees, bahamas, jamaican-citizens

I am a Jamaican citizen granted asylum in the United States I want to find out if I could use my   refugee travel documents to visit the Bahamas?

Comment: Timatic seems to indicate you may need a visa https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true but I couldn’t readily confirm this on https://www.immigration.gov.bs

Comment: Do you have a valid Jamaican passport?  If so, [this page](https://www.immigration.gov.bs/before-your-arrival/) indicates that you do not need a passport for a 3-month (possibly an 8-month) visit.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Using a Jamaican passport might put their protected status at risk.

Comment: I lived in The Bahamas for a few years during university and know that travel documents other than passports need visas. Unfortunately, I can't link to anything official, but a call to the nearest Bahamian embassy would help

Comment: @Kina answers based on personal experience are fine, especially if nothing official is to be found online.  I encourage you to add one.

Answer (score 3):

Today, Timatic now says that:

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> - Passengers with a US Travel Document (Form I-571) issued to refugees with nationality of Jamaica shown on the bio-data page of the travel document.
> - Passengers with a Permit to Re-Enter (Form I-327) issued by the USA with nationality of Jamaica shown on the bio-data page of the travel document.

Particularly note that you don't need a Jamaican passport, or in fact any other passport, when using the Refugee Travel Document. It is a substitute for a passport and like a passport it will hold all of your visas and entry/exit stamps.

> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with a Permit to Re-Enter (Form I-327) issued by the USA.
> - Passengers with a US Travel Document (Form I-571) issued to refugees.

You are still required to take a COVID-19 RT-PCR test within five days of arrival and obtain the [Travel Health Visa](https://www.travel.gov.bs/international) before departure. Regarding this, Timatic says:

> - Passengers must complete a  Bahamas Health Visa  application at [www.travel.gov.bs](http://www.travel.gov.bs) before departure. They must upload their negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) RT-PCR test result or select relevant exemption category, and provide their contact information. Passengers must present the approved Bahamas Health Visa  application at check-in and upon arrival.
> - Passengers must have a negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) RT-PCR test result from a sample dated at most 5 days before arrival.